# How to auto close wordpress page after sometime?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have been struggling with this idea where i would want to auto close the woocommerce thank you page after 1 minute or so, but am unable to find a way out. The reason behind the same is because we are tracking it with Facebook Pixels. So, 1 views is counted as a sale.

So, we need to ensure, the customer can only view it once and not revisit it again. Is is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redirect to any page after 1 minute from WooCommerce thank you page. I have tried below code to redirect to a home page after 60 seconds from thank you page.

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'custom_redirect_after_purchase');

function custom_redirect_after_purchase() {

    global $wp;

    if (is_checkout() && !empty($wp->query_vars['order-received'])) {
        header( "refresh:60;url=".home_url() );
    }
}
```

I hope this helps you to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to redirect using PHP and WordPress is like below you can try this

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'custom_redirect_after_purchase');

function custom_redirect_after_purchase() {

    global $wp;

    if (is_checkout() && !empty($wp->query_vars['order-received'])) {
        sleep(60);
        wp_redirect( home_url() ); exit;
    }
}
```